# ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions . Stacking vectors

Tags: python, numpy, stack, append

l have three arrays to append.
Here a sample of my vectors :

```
V1=array([ 0.03317591, -0.01624349, -0.01151019])
V2=array([[ 0.06865846, -0.00223798],
       [-0.02872752, -0.00369226],
       [-0.02063454, -0.00231726]])
V3=
array([[ 0.01160267,  0.12610824, -0.01634712,  0.01217519],
       [-0.00727594, -0.0501376 , -0.01641992,  0.00933081],
       [-0.05305551,  0.01195211,  0.04031831, -0.04476306]])
```

in order to append the three vectors and get one vector l did the following :

```
new_v=np.hstack((V1,V2,V3))
```

l got the following error :

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

However :

```
 V2_V3=np.hstack((V2,V3))
```

works, it returns :

```
array([[ 0.06865846, -0.00223798,  0.01160267,  0.12610824, -0.01634712,
         0.01217519],
       [-0.02872752, -0.00369226, -0.00727594, -0.0501376 , -0.01641992,
         0.00933081],
       [-0.02063454, -0.00231726, -0.05305551,  0.01195211,  0.04031831,
        -0.04476306]])
```

What l would like to get is the following :

```
array([[0.03317591, 0.06865846, -0.00223798,  0.01160267,  0.12610824, -0.01634712,
         0.01217519],
       [-0.01624349, -0.02872752, -0.00369226, -0.00727594, -0.0501376 , -0.01641992,
         0.00933081],
       [-0.01151019, -0.02063454, -0.00231726, -0.05305551,  0.01195211,  0.04031831,
        -0.04476306]])
```

What is wrong with V1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `np.hstack`, we need to convert `V1` to `2D` such that the lengths along the first axis for the three input arrays are the same -

```
np.hstack((V1[:,None],V2,V3))
```

As alternatives, we can use [`np.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) or [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) along the second axis on `2D` converted `V1` alongwith others or [`np.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html) -

```
np.column_stack((V1,V2,V3))
np.concatenate([V1[:,None],V2,V3],axis=1)
np.c_[V1,V2,V3]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with V1 except that it's 1D while V2 and V3 are 2D. According to the [docs for hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html), all the input arrays have to have the same shape on all except the second axis. V1 in your code doesn't have a second axis.

You can easily add an empty second axis to V1 during your call to hstack like this:

```
new_v = hstack((V1[:, None], V2, V3))
```

That should achieve your desired output.

**Note:** The `V1[:, None]` bit is one of three ways that NumPy has available to add empty dimensions to arrays. The other two are `V1[:, np.newaxis]` and the function version `np.expand_dims(V1, axis=1)`.

You could use any of these in place of `V1[:, None]` in that line of code and it would work. Check out the [docs for numpy.expand_dims](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) for more on adding dimensions to arrays.